# How to count the index of an element using jquery in a separated list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

*Please note that the below is an overly simplified version of my real code.*

I have an event binding to a parent element of a list set:

```
var index;

$('.gallery').on('click', '.img', function(){
  index = $(this).index();
});
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <ul>
    <li class="wrapper"><img src="img.png" alt=""></li>
    <li class="wrapper"><img src="img.png" alt=""></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="wrapper"><img src="img.png" alt=""></li>
    <li class="wrapper"><img src="img.png" alt=""></li>
    <li class="wrapper"><img src="img.png" alt=""></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How do I capture the `img`'s index when I click on it's wrapper in the global context of all the li's under `.gallery`?

i.e. If I click on the fifth image `index` would be 4 and not 2.

A possible solution would be to add `data-index` to all my `li`s but I wan't to know if I can do this using JavaScript only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add selector argument in [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method:

```
$('.gallery').on('click', 'img', function() {
    var index = $(this).index('.wrapper img');
    // ...
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Rb53r/

[Explanation from jQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/index/#entry-longdesc):

> If a selector string is passed as an argument, .index() returns an
>   integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery
>   object relative to the elements matched by the selector.

Comment: First off, thanks that was fast :) Secondly how does that work?

Comment: @hitautodestruct Selector argument tells `.index()` method to create a collection of elements in which the current (i.e. clicked) element should be found, and returns its index if found.

Comment: Great!, Thanks for this. I've added a quote from the jQuery site. I just noticed this after you answered and I went to check it out.